# Use of empty enum after switching to XCode6

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6

After loading an iPad project in XCode 6, I see "parse issue: use of empty enum" in UIDevice.h.

[image]

The problem goes away if I set the `Base SDK` to 8.1 (latest), but not if I set it to 7.1. `__IPHONE_3_2` is less than both of those, so don't quite get it!

Comment: Which simulator are you using? Do you get the same issue when using the iPhone 6 simulator?

Comment: What's the Deployment Target?

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too in XCode 6.1.1 and "fixed it" by downgrading back to XCode 6.1.  You can just remove XCode from your applications and then install Xcode 6.1 from the apple developer downloads site.

https://developer.apple.com/downloads

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I'm seeing this too on XCode 6.1.1 and CocoaPods 0.35.0. Would rather not have to go back to 6.1 but hey ho!...

Answer (score 1):

This error popped up for me when I upgraded to Xcode 6.2, but only when building for the simulator, not when building for a device. I had installed the iOS 7.1 SDK from Xcode 5 into Xcode 6.2, because I have a legacy project that we haven't yet updated for iOS 8. On this project I have the `Base SDK` set to iOS 7.1.

I fixed it by installing the iOS 7 SDK for the simulator from Xcode 5 into Xcode 6.2. Xcode apparently processes `#if __IPHONE_3_2 <= __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED` wrong when the base SDK is set to iOS 7 but that SDK is not actually available.

To install the iOS 7 SDKs into Xcode 6, start by getting a copy of Xcode 5. Apple makes old versions of Xcode available to developers at https://developer.apple.com/downloads. The SDK's are in `Xcode.app ▸ Contents ▸ Developer ▸ Platforms ▸ iPhoneSimulator.platform ▸ Developer ▸ SDKs` and `Xcode.app ▸ Contents ▸ Developer ▸ Platforms ▸ iPhoneOS.platform ▸ Developer ▸ SDKs`. Move them to the same location in Xcode 6.